# Mac iBookG4--MsWord and Safari Error

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, safari

I have mac ibook G4.
Ms office (word) gives me error when I start the program and doesn't open. Also Safari closes unexpectedly while I am browsing.
I created another user account. I did follow MS troubleshooting steps. But it's still the same issue. In safe-mode/boot Microsoft-Word working properly.
What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're using; at the latest OS X 10.4 right? honestly, I'd do a complete reinstall of both your OS and your apps, because the amount of cruft is probably off the charts.

btw the fact that safe boot fixes it, means that it's an issue with a cache somewhere, good luck finding it man.